# What’s wrong with this ASP Code; how would you fix it

Tags: asp-classic

When i run the script it says

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01f5'
>
> Illegal assignment: 'MAX_AGE'
>
> /classic.asp, line 8

This is the script:

```
response.Write(GetMaxAge())
Function GetMaxAge()

    const MAX_AGE = 50
    Dim iRtnValue

    MAX_AGE = 45

    iRtnValue = MAX_AGE

    GetStudentAge = iRtnValue

End Function
```

Comment: How is MAX_AGE declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning GetStudentAge instead of GetMaxAge. I mean "GetStudentAge = iRtnValue"

Answer (score 5):

MAX_AGE is defined as a constant. You cant change the value of a constant

Answer (score 1):

```
const MAX_AGE = 50
```

You have specified `MAX_AGE` as a constant. Any specific reason that you are changing it later: `MAX_AGE = 45` ? You are treating a constant as a variable.